# I have node server running on AWS EC2 t2.medium,created AMI,launch template and auto scaling. EBS is attached. Node server is not running new instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

In resource instance, Node server is running on Port 3000, Health check is failed for new instance. when I checked no process is running on port 3000.
I did not add any user data during launch template.
Resources are getting created but new instance do not have the desired server

Process is running successfully on parent instance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.